# I am trying to solve this problem, i had tried but i dont know how to resolve this problem via code or logically

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures

A single array A[1....MAXSIZE] is used to implements two stacks. the two stacks grow from opposite ends of the array. variable top1 and top2(top1 < top2) point to the location of the topmost element in each of the stacks. If the space is to be used efficiently, determine the condition for stack-full?

Comment: is there code snippet or anything i can start from, that you have tried ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is just a homework dump.

Answer (score 1):

Both stacks are full when the 2 tops collide.

```
[e1|e2|e3|_|_|_|_|f2|f1]
        |          |
       top1        top2
```

This means stacks are full if `top1+1 == top2`
 or of course if `top2==0` or `top1==MAXSIZE-1`

Note that both stacks are sharing the same space. So if your array is full both stacks are full, otherwise any of the 2 stacks can possibly take one more element.
That explains why this condition above applies to both stacks.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie the condition is the same for both stacks. switched to plural to make this clearer

Comment: @PaulOgilvie not sure to follow. for me `top+1==top2 <=> top1==top2-1`

Comment: Note: arrays are indexed `0..n-1` so `top2==0` or `top1==MAXSIZE-1`. And that condition is included in `top1+1 == top2` Sorry to have confused you.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie yes thanks, fixed it (the question says A[1....MAXSIZE], but it is tagged C)

Answer (score 0):

For implementing two stacks by using a single array we can simply take int variables say top1 = -1 and top2 = n, top1 represent the current position of the element in stack1 and top2 represent the current position of the element in stack2. 
Listed below is the code of push, pop, and top for both stacks.

**Stack1 :**

```
/*** push **/
void push_stack1(int element_value ){
    if (top1 >= top2 -1 )
        cout << "array if full (overflow)";
    else
        arr[++top1] = element_value;
}

/*** pop ***/
int pop_stack1 (){
    if(top1 < 0)
        cout << "no element in stack1 under-flow";
    else
        cout << arr[top1--];
}

/*** top ***/
int top_stack1(){ 
    if (top1 < 0)
        cout << "stack1 is smepty ";
    else 
        cout << arr[top1];
}
```

**Stack2 :**

```
/*** push **/
void push_stack2(int element_value ){
    if (top2 <= top1 + 1 )
        cout << "array if full (overflow)";
    else
        arr[--top2] = element_value;
}


/*** pop ***/
int pop_stack2 (){
    if(top2 > n-1)
        cout << "no element in stack2 under-flow";
    else
        cout << arr[top2++];
}

/*** top ***/
int top_stack2() { 
    if (top2 > n-1)
        cout << "stack2 is smepty ";
    else 
        cout << arr[top2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On every full check, you can implement the following:

```
bool ifFull(int top1,int top2){
    if(top2-top1==1)
       return true;
return false;
}
```

But if the program is a part of larger program, then there can be a more optimised way using bitwise-XOR.

```
bool ifFull(int top1,int top2){
    if((top2-top1)~1)
       return false;
return true;
}
```

In contrast to previous method which uses a logical and an arithmetic operator, the second method only uses an arithmetic and a bitwise operator which is comparatively faster.